# Use of ACD to model transaction durations

Tags: time-series, market-microstructure, econometrics, models, duration

I am using a simple [ACD (autoregressive conditional duration) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_duration) with expoential or Burr distributed residuals and 1 lag, i.e. ACD(1,1).

I am modelling durations for transactions data on a 'medium' liquidity market.

I obtain a correct fit, but not very good out-of-sample results.
Does anyone have experience with handling this model on real data? and using it for out-of-sample prediction.

I am interested by practitioner's ressource: code, tutorial, example, notebooks, etc. or direct feedback.

Comment: you really have to elaborate on what you meant by "not very good out-of-sample results". Fitting a ARMA-GARCH(1,1) on any log-return isn't going to give you similar fluctuation but a predicted direction with .5 and .1 confidence intervals. This applies to almost any attempt on financial time series analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested several Multiplicative Errors Models, including the standard ACD model. I used these models to forecast the bid ask spread ( non-negative data) and I obtain interesting results. As a main information I have found that the choice of the error term distribution is pivotal with the Burr distribution being by far the best  (tested: Exp, Weibull, Generalized Gamma). Also I have found that long memory models (FIACD by Jasiak (1998), LMACD by Karanasos (2003)) have better out-of-sample density forecast accuracy  than other MEM models. So I recommend you to test these latter models. Finally I have compared those models with ARMA ones and found that MEM models should be preferable for tails forecasts.

I plan to release freely the code (in [Ox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ox_(programming_language))) that I made to estimate those models, I still need to do a minimal help documentation. I'll edit this answer when I'll do it.

Comment: few years later, mind sharing your interesting findings on bid-ask spread forecast ?